# I've two swap partitions, how can i delete one?

Tags: linux, swap

I've installed Ubuntu on my computer but I did a mistake during the installation and it created two swap's.

In fact I had tree partitions (system, home, swap) but the installator crashed so I restarted the installation and it has installed everything in the system partition.

So now I separated the home in the appropriate partition but I've two swap partitions.

How can I delete one ? If I delete one, how will it go ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can safely delete one of the swap partitions using gparted disk management utility.
but first remove its by running command

> swapoff /dev/"swap parition"

and then delete, entry from /etc/fstab , so that it might not try to mount it again on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Boot with a LiveCD and use gparted to remove the swap partition. You can then resize the space however you'd like.

Comment: no need to use a livecd.

Comment: If you want to expand a filesystem that's mounted you'd need to use a livecd.